# Cast a multidimensional cv::Mat to std::vector<cv::Mat>&

Tags: c++, opencv

if i have a variable like this:

```
cv::Mat data[3];
```

how can i pass it in a function which need an input like:

```
void function_name(std::vector<cv::Mat>& data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a vector and initialise it with array and pass it to `function_name()` function:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> v(data, data + (sizeof data / sizeof data[0]));
function_name (v);
```

Other way could be to pass a temporary object but, in that case, the `function_name()` parameter should be `const`. Only viable if you are not making any changes to parameter `data` in `function_name()`:

```
void function_name(const std::vector<cv::Mat>& data);
                   ^^^^^
```

with this change, you can call `function_name()` function like this:

```
function_name (std::vector<cv::Mat>(data, data + (sizeof data / sizeof data[0])));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function that takes a `cv::Mat*` and returns an `std::vector<cv::Mat>`

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> ptrToVec(cv::Mat* matPtr){
    int index=0;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> ret;
    while(matPtr) 
        ret.push_back(matPtr[index++]);

    return ret;
}
```